# IntelliJ Applet Debugger Disconnects after 15-20 secs of break point hit

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, applet

I am trying to debug Applet and attached the debugger in IntelliJ and break point is being hit successfully. But after 15-20 secs Java Console exits and debugger also disconnects.

I am unable to find any solution for this issue. I am using Java 8 and Intellij 14.1.4.

This issue was with previous version of Intellij as well.

Please help me with the issue and let me know if you need anymore details.

Comment: I am not sure that this is the issue of Intellij Idea, however, you might prove it if you cannot reproduce the same issue with Eclipse, for example.

Comment: It looks like the issue is with IntelliJ itself, as the debugger works fine in Eclipse.